# Which of these subsets are subgroups, and if they are, which are abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Determine which subsets $H$ are subgroups and if they are, which are abelian.

1. Let $G = \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ and let $$H = \left\{A\in\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})\ \middle\vert \det(A) = a^2-b^2\sqrt{2}, a,b\in\mathbb{Q},\textrm{ and at least one of }a,b\textrm{ is nonzero}\right\}.$$
   My attempt: if we consider $AB$, where $A,B\in H$, the diagonal elements are irrational since the product of an irrational and rational is irrational, so $H$ cannot be a subgroup.
2. Let $G = \{(x,y)\mid x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then $G$ is a group under the operation $$(x,y)*(x',y')=(x+x',y+y').$$ Let $H = \{(x,y) \in G\mid xy \ge 0\}$. I'm not quite sure how to approach this one.
3. Let $G = \operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and let $H = \{A \in G\mid A^2 = I\}$
   My attempt: since $A^2 = I$ we know $A$ is an involution, so $\det(A)= -a^2 - (1-a)^2$, so for $A,B \in H$, $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ but I'm not really sure how to show that $AB$ is in $H$.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: In **(1)**, how do you conclude anything about diagonals? The definition of $H$ is in terms of determinants, not diagonals. In **(2)**, what is $(1,2)*(-2,-1)$? In **(3)**, what is the point of your reasoning about determinants? You _already_ know that $\det AB = (\det A)(\det B)$ for all matrices in $G$. What you should be concerned about here is whether $(AB)^2=I$.

Answer (score 1):

1. For $H$ to be a subgroup you know it has to be closed.  What do you know about $\operatorname{det}(AB)$?
2. The identity is going to be $(0,0)$.  Now consider the inverse of $(1,0)$ added to the element $(0,1)$.
3. Again this reduces to finding $A,B$ such that $A^2=B^2=I$ but $(AB)^2\not= I$.  If $(AB)^2=I$ then $(AB)^2=A^2B^2$, which is only true if $A$ and $B$ commute (why?).  Can you find some noncommuting involutions?

Answer (score 1):

For problem one, here's a hint: if $H \subset G$ is a subgroup, and $\phi: K \to G$ is a map, then $\phi^{-1}(H)$ is a group. Conversely (sort of), if $L \subset H$ and $\phi(L)$ is not a subgroup, then $L$ is not a subgroup.

Consider $K = GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ mapping to $G = \mathbb{R}^\times$ via the determinant. You are reduced to checking whether the set of elements of the form $a^2 - \sqrt{2}b^2$ for $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$, not both zero, is a group under multiplication.